# Plotting a new point value in a boxplot. R and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a simple data frame called msq:

```
    sex wing    index
1   h   54      67.4
2   m   60.5    67.9
3   m   60      64.5
4   m   59      66.6
5   m   63.5    63.3
6   m   63      66.7
7   m   61.5    71.8
8   m   62      67.9
9   m   63      67.8
10  m   62.5    72.7
11  m   61.5    70.3
12  h   54.5    70.7
13  m   60      61.1
14  m   63.5    50.9
15  m   63      72.1
```

My intention is to make a boxplot with ggplot for which I use this code that works fine:

```
gplot(msq, aes("index",index))+ geom_boxplot (aes(group="sex"))
```

and then to plot an outlier that should stand alone up in the graph (a value 73.9). The problem is that if I include it in the data set, the boxplot "absorbs" it making the error line longer... I have been looking in Hmisc and to stat_summary but I can't get any clear idea.

thank you.

Comment: I just need to add a point in y=73.8.Yes, thanks for the "" comment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `geom_point` to add points to a plot generated with `ggplot2`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(msq, aes(sex, index)) +   # Note. I modified the aes call
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(aes(y = 73.9)) # add points
```

[image]

Comment: @Arun I suppose it's better to use `geom_point`. I modified the answer.

Comment: I did not mean the command. `annotate` and `geom_point` does the job for sure. But do you think it is appropriate to decide the outliers? Although I understand that's what the OP is asking for. Just wanted to know what others think in this matter.

Comment: @Arun I fully agree. This is not the right way to deal with outliers. But since the OP wants to avoid longer boxplot lines (what I think is incorrect), there seems to be not other way.

Comment: Thank you! it is exactly what I needed. I know this is not the normal way to plot an outlier, but the thing is that 73.9 is a single observation I think belongs to another population.